# Porque Mozilla no me reconoce display-Flex?

Tags: css, html5, css3, flexbox

Asi se ven las imagenes en Chrome:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y asi se ven en Mozilla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando le quito la propiedad display-flex se ve bien. Porque no la reconoce?

```
 .edificios_container_item {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
text-align: center;
height: auto;
margin-right: 80px;
```

}

```
 .edificios_container {
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
 }
```

Comment: Por favor publica tambien el codigo, que no podemos ayudarte sin ver el codigo

Comment: ahi lo republique, gracias!

Comment: Claramente el problema estaria en `height`, en mi experiencia es una de las propiedades que mas problemas causa al iniciar con css, intenta definiendo un height estático  ya sea en en px, em, rem u otro, pero definelo.

Comment: Piensa que el width y el heigth estan estáticos y estos factores afectan a la propiedad flex, yo uso firefox y no tengo problemas. La verdad es que yo tambien soy un poco primerizo en flex-box pero si pasas el código HTML tal vez te pueda ayudar mejor.

Comment: Podrías compartir también el HTML de eso? Uno de los errores comunes entre distintos exploradores es que todos tienen su versión de default para las etiquetas, una solución a eso es resetear a una versión estable como este https://gist.github.com/DavidWells/18e73022e723037a50d6.